# About CodeIgniter structure

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-503

I have a project based on codeigniter. I already have a model that extends some CI_Model class. `class Playermodel extends CI_Model` . I need to import Playermodel in one of my classes so that I can easily access database without hard coding the connection with php.

However this CI_Model class is making me trouble coz I cannot really find a file with CI_Model class. Also when I import it I get `internal server error 503`.

What should I do in this case and where can I find this CI_Model class?

Thanks

Comment: in which class your trying to load the model? is it a library or a controller?

Comment: Well I import it in my view playerview.php. Should I use controller instead or custom php page? Anyway what is the best method to used CI connection to db instead of hard coding it in my file?

Comment: Can you call a model class from any view page in MVC???

Comment: @Vlad I think you need to learn Codeigniter first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your models will typically be loaded and called from within your controller functions. To load a model you will use the following function:

```
$this->load->model('Model_name')
```

The DB connection settings are stored in `application/config/database.php` you dont need to hardcord it int your files. Then to connect to database

`$this->load->database();`

Read the revelant user_guide [model](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html) [database](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html)